# Reactjs does not make use of env url in docker container

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

my reactjs communicates with backend api but I used docker compose to build an image with the react app

now the api is no long working

my react .env contains this

REACT_APP_DEV_BASE_URL="http://localhost:7500/api/"

instead of the above url what I see in the network tab is this

http://localhost:3000/undefined/auth/login

The api works with with postman but react is not working

Any solutions?

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.17 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package.json
COPY package-lock.json package-lock.json
COPY public/ public
COPY src/ src
RUN npm ci
 RUN npm run build
 FROM nginx:1.23.4-alpine as production
 ENV NODE_ENV production
 ENV REACT_APP_DEV_BASE_URL http://localhost:7500/api/
 COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
 COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
 EXPOSE 80
 CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
 HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s CMD ping -c 1 172.17.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

If Node api running on 7500 port then pass proxy in `package.json` file in react.
and you also use nginx server so if nginx serve response from backend then you use `nginx:7500` instead of `localhost:7500`